# facebook page access token using php?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to figure out how I can get a `page access token` using php. everything I do will not return the access token.

the first code bellow, works and it post the message as the user. but I need to post as a page and according to documentation, i will need a page access token to be able to post as a page/app.

so I've edited my working code (first code) to the second code (returns a blank page).

could someone please let me know whats missing or what I am doing wrong?

working code that posts as user:

```
<?php
 include_once 'inc/facebook.php';

 $appId = '00000000000000000';
 $secret = '00000000000000000000000000000';
 $returnurl = 'https://mydomain.com';
 $permissions = 'manage_pages, publish_actions';

 $fb = new Facebook(array('appId'=>$appId, 'secret'=>$secret));

 $fbuser = $fb->getUser();



 if($fbuser){

    if(isset($_POST['msg']) and $_POST['msg']!=''){
        try{


            $message = array(
                'message' => $_POST['msg']
            );
            $posturl = '/'.$_POST['pageid'].'/feed';
            $result = $fb->api($posturl,'POST',$message);
            if($result){
                echo 'Successfully posted to Facebook Wall...';
            }
        }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    try{
        $qry = 'select page_id, name from page where page_id in (select page_id from page_admin where uid ='.$fbuser.')';
        $pages = $fb->api(array('method' => 'fql.query','query' => $qry));

        if(empty($pages)){
            echo 'The user does not have any pages.';
        }else{
            echo '<form action="" method="post">';
            echo 'Select Page: <select name="pageid">';
            foreach($pages as $page){
                echo '<option value="'.$page['page_id'].'">'.$page['name'].'</option>';
            }
            echo '</select>';
            echo '<br />Message: <textarea name="msg"></textarea>';
            echo '<br /><input type="submit" value="Post to wall" />';
            echo '</form>';
        }

    }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

 }else{
    $fbloginurl = $fb->getLoginUrl(array('redirect-uri'=>$returnurl, 'scope'=>$permissions));
    echo '<a href="'.$fbloginurl.'">Login with Facebook</a>';
 }



 echo $page_info['access_token']
?>
```

**second/edited code which returns a blank page when viewed from a browser:**

```
<?php
 include_once 'inc/facebook.php';

 $appId = '0000000000000';
 $secret = '000000000000000000000000000';
 $returnurl = 'https://mydomain.com';
 $permissions = 'manage_pages, publish_actions';

 $fb = new Facebook(array('appId'=>$appId, 'secret'=>$secret));

 $fbuser = $fb->getUser();

 if($fbuser){

    if(isset($_POST['msg']) and $_POST['msg']!=''){
        try{

            $page_info = $facebook->api("/$pageId?fields=access_token");
            if (!empty($page_info['access_token'])) {


            $message = array(
            'access_token' => $page_info['access_token'],
                'message' => $_POST['msg']
            );
            $posturl = '/'.$_POST['pageid'].'/feed';
            $result = $fb->api($posturl,'POST',$message);
            if($result){
                echo 'Successfully posted to Facebook Wall...';
            }
            }
        }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }


    try{
        $qry = 'select page_id, name from page where page_id in (select page_id from page_admin where uid ='.$fbuser.')';
        $pages = $fb->api(array('method' => 'fql.query','query' => $qry));

        if(empty($pages)){
            echo 'The user does not have any pages.';
        }else{
            echo '<form action="" method="post">';
            echo 'Select Page: <select name="pageid">';
            foreach($pages as $page){
                echo '<option value="'.$page['page_id'].'">'.$page['name'].'</option>';
            }
            echo '</select>';
            echo '<br />Message: <textarea name="msg"></textarea>';
            echo '<br /><input type="submit" value="Post to wall" />';
            echo '</form>';
        }


    }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

 }else{
    $fbloginurl = $fb->getLoginUrl(array('redirect-uri'=>$returnurl, 'scope'=>$permissions));
    echo '<a href="'.$fbloginurl.'">Login with Facebook</a>';
 }

?>
```

**EDIT, This will generate an access token but I am not sure if it is a page access token or it is a user access token because the access token is the same for all the pages:**

```
 include_once 'inc/facebook.php';

 $appId = '000000000000000000';
 $secret = '000000000000000000000000000000';
 $returnurl = 'https://mydomain.com';
 $permissions = 'manage_pages, publish_actions';

 $fb = new Facebook(array('appId'=>$appId, 'secret'=>$secret));

 $fbuser = $fb->getUser();

 if($fbuser){

    if(isset($_POST['msg']) and $_POST['msg']!=''){
        try{


            $message = array(
                'message' => $_POST['msg']
            );
            $posturl = '/'.$_POST['pageid'].'/feed';


            //$posturl2 = '/'.$_POST['pageid'].'/tabs';

            //$result2 = $fb->api($posturl2,"post", array("access_token" => $pageAccessToken,  "app_id" => $appId));


            $result = $fb->api($posturl,'POST',$message);
            if($result){
                echo 'Successfully posted to Facebook Wall...';
            }
        }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    try{
        $qry = 'select page_id, name from page where page_id in (select page_id from page_admin where uid ='.$fbuser.')';
        $pages = $fb->api(array('method' => 'fql.query','query' => $qry));


        $pageIds=$fb->api('/me/accounts');
        $pageAccessToken=$pageIds["data"][1]["access_token"];




        if(empty($pages)){
            echo 'The user does not have any pages.';
        }else{
            echo '<form action="" method="post">';
            echo 'Select Page: <select name="pageid">';
            foreach($pages as $page){
                echo '<option value="'.$page['page_id'].'">'.$page['name'].'</option>';
            }
            echo '</select>';


                        echo 'Select Page: <select name="pageid">';
            foreach($pageIds as $pageId){
                echo '<option value="'.$page['page_id'].'">'.$pageAccessToken.'</option>';
            }
            echo '</select>';


            echo '<br />Message: <textarea name="msg"></textarea>';
            echo '<br /><input type="submit" value="Post to wall" />';
            echo '</form>';
        }

    }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

 }else{
    $fbloginurl = $fb->getLoginUrl(array('redirect-uri'=>$returnurl, 'scope'=>$permissions));
    echo '<a href="'.$fbloginurl.'">Login with Facebook</a>';
 }



 echo $pageAccessToken;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not really possible for me to go through your bunch of code . But what you want is quite simple. Just follow the following steps-

(I'll start after the user successfully grants `manage_pages` and `publish_stream` permissions)

1. Get the [**page access token**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#pagetokens)-

   ```
   \GET /{page-id}?fields=access_token
   ```
2. Use the page access token to post a feed on the page-

   ```
   \POST /{page-id}/feed?fields=page_access_token //send any parameters with this
   ```

That's it!

Comment: I've already managed to do it but is there any chance you could take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24683378/200-user-does-not-have-sufficient-administrative-permission-for-this-action-o/24683602#24683602

Answer (score 0):

These access tokens are similar to user access tokens, except that they provide permission to APIs that read, write or modify the data belonging to a Facebook Page. To obtain a page access token you need to start by obtaining a user access token and asking for the manage_pages permission. Once you have the user access token you then get the page access token via the Graph API.
 Once this permission has been granted, you can retrieve the page access token using the following Graph API request:

> GET /{user-id}/accounts

Read this Page
[Page Access Tokens][1]

[1] https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Comment: that will only get a user access token or application access token. what I need is the Page Access Token. I have already tried that and it will get the token but it won't work for what i am trying to do as its a user token.

Comment: sorry your second edit is a bit confusing! can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: tried this and didn't work. `$pageIds=$fb->api('GET /'.$fbuser.'/accounts');` any idea?

Comment: Did it give any output.??

Comment: no, nothing. I did put `echo $pageIds;` at the bottom of the page. and it doesn't out out anything.

Comment: did you check if $fbuser has some value..?? check on graph explorer

Comment: yes, the fbuser has some value. I have edited my question with a new code which generates a token but I'm not sure if the token is a page token or user token because it is the same for all the pages. could you please advise on that?

Comment: check the response in console. If the object has fields category, name, access token and perms associated with it, that access token is the page access token

Comment: not sure what you mean by checking the response in console. what response and what console?

Comment: var_dump() sorry :P . How do you know it generates a token?? whatever variable gets this value put it into var_dump() to check the result

Comment: I know it generates the token because I can see it on my page.                     `echo 'Select Page: <select name="pageid">';
            foreach($pageIds as $pageId){
                echo '<option value="'.$page['page_id'].'">'.$pageAccessToken.'</option>';
            }
            echo '</select>';`

Comment: also, var_dump($pageAccessToken) will only echo the string of the token.

Comment: match this token to the result from graph explorer query. If both are same that  means you have the pagetoken. In graph explorer. set a GET request v2.0/me/accounts and see the result to check

Comment: they're not the same and every time I refresh my page, the token changes to a new one.

Comment: Let me tell you in some time then