# (#200) User does not have sufficient administrative permission for this action on this page

Tags: php

After 5 days of trial and error I am getting very close to what I want to do.

with one exception. my current code only works once.

here is the scenario,

I am trying to `Add A Page Tab` to a facebook page using facebook sdk.

my current code works in a way but it will only work for the first facebook page that was created in facebook and if I try to add a page tab for other pages, it will throw the following error:

```
(#200) User does not have sufficient administrative permission for this action on this page
```

i do not understand why this is happening. this error usually means that I do not have a page access token but if that was the case, my code won't/shouldn't work for the first page either but it does!

any chance someone could take a look at my current code to see what I am doing wrong?

any help would be appreciated.

my current code as follows:

This is the part to get the access token and also after form submission:

```
// Set Extended Access Token




if (isset($code)) {


$fb->setExtendedAccessToken();

//Get access short live access token
$accessToken = $fb->getAccessToken();

// Exchange token
$fb->api('/oauth/access_token', 'POST',
array(  
    'grant_type' => 'fb_exchange_token',           
    'client_id' => $appId ,
    'client_secret' => $secret,
    'fb_exchange_token' => $accessToken
    )
    );

        $token_url="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" .  $appId 
        . "&client_secret=" . $secret 
        . "&code=" . $code 
        . "&redirect_uri=" . $returnurl;


    $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
    $params = null;
    parse_str($response, $params);
    $user_access_token = $params['access_token'];
    $attachment_1 = array(
    'access_token' => $user_access_token
);

}

$result = $fb->api("/me/accounts", $attachment_1);
    foreach($result["data"] as $page) {
        if($page["page_id"] == $page_id) {
            $page_access_token = $page["access_token"];
            //echo $page_access_token;
            break;
        }
    }



        //$pageIds=$fb->api('/me/accounts');
        //$pageAccessToken=$pageIds["data"][1]["access_token"];







        if(isset($_POST['msg']) and $_POST['msg']!=''){

        try{

        $message = array(
                'access_token' => $page_access_token,
                'message' => $_POST['msg']
            );
            $posturl = '/'.$_POST['pageid'].'/feed';

            $posturl2 = '/'.$_POST['pageid'].'/tabs';


            $fb->api($posturl2, 'POST', array(
           'app_id'=>'0000000000000000000000000',
           'access_token'=>$page_access_token



));
        $result = $fb->api($posturl,'POST', $message);

        if($result){


            echo 'Successfully posted to Facebook Wall...';
        }
    }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

and this is how I populate the users pages in a form within my page:

```
if(empty($pages)){
            echo 'The user does not have any pages.';
        }else{
            echo '<form action="" method="post">';
            echo 'Select Page: <select name="pageid">';
            echo '<option value="">Select A Page</option>';
            foreach($pages as $page){
                echo '<option value="'.$page['page_id'].'">'.$page['name'].'</option>';
            }
            echo '</select>';


            //echo 'Select Page: <select name="pageid2">';
           // foreach($pageIds as $pageId){
               // echo '<option value="'.$page['page_id'].'">'.$pageAccessToken.'</option>';
           // }
            //echo '</select>';


            echo '<br />Message: <textarea name="msg"></textarea>';
            echo '<br /><input type="submit" value="Post to wall" />';
            echo '</form>';
        }

    }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: @SahilMittal, without this much code you wouldn't know how my script works though so someone else would say "why you haven't posted enough code"! also, this is is not that much code. its only a few lines. most of it is commented code anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same error message with a Realtime API subscription. I assume it´s the same problem, you don´t have Admin rights for the Page. You can still get a Page Token for a Page if you are Moderator (for example), but certain things are not possible if you are not Admin (Subscribing to the Realtime API, adding a Tab).

Comment: Here is the list of Role abilities: https://www.facebook.com/help/289207354498410
When luschn says "Manager", I assume he means "Moderator", since there is no "Manager" role.

Comment: yeah, that´s what i meant, thanx :)